# How do I show text and a button? (android)

Tags: android

I'm working on an app that generates a random quote (from a switch) when you press a button. This then goes to the next screen, where it then displays it as a textView. That part works. I want a button under this, which would send the user back to the main screen (I also plan on having two other buttons but those will come later). However, the app is only displaying either the text or the button, not both.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_comp_out);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText("Main Menu");
    button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
    button.setHeight(75);


    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
    setContentView(button);
}
```

This is the code I'm using to create the text output and the button. the String message is the quote. This code is making a button that fills the whole screen though.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@color/orange">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:text="@string/button_menu" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Without the java code making a button, I was using this, which wasn't making a button either. (Also the background wasn't being set to orange, but thats not a big deal) Any ideas on how to put the button under the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have **3** `setContentView()` instructions (the second and the third override the first one, which is **why you see only a button** - the one you define in code - and **don't get the orange background**, anymore).
There must be only **1**.

This instruction is used to set the Activity (or Fragment) layout which should contain both your components.

Try something like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_comp_out);

    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    // Add a click handler for your button - choose one of the possible methods (see the link at the end of this answer).

    // The following instructions should go inside the click handler.
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
}
```

**activity_comp_out.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@color/orange"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:text="@string/text_menu"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:text="@string/button_menu"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Several possible methods to handle View (not only Buttons) clicks are illustrated here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_event_handling.htm

Answer (score 0):

`setContentView()` is used to inflate your layout, you need to grab the button object from your inflated layout:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

You can do the same with your TextView once you add it to the layout.